# How to get Last ID of created data from related model?

Tags: laravel-5

I can't fetch last id of created data from related model.

I tried to use `$alacarte->id` but it doesnt get the right ID of the model.

```
$order = array(
            'os_id' => $orderSlip->id,
            'group_id' => $menu['group_id'],
            'size' => $menu['size'],
        );


$alacarte = $this->menu->find($menu['id']);

$alacarte->orders()->create($order)->save();

return $alacarte->id;
```

I expect the output of the last created order to be the ID of `Model\Order`, but the actual output is the ID of the `Model\Menu`.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

I just removed `save()` after creation.

`$menu = $alacarte->orders()->create($order)->save()`

changed to

`$menu = $alacarte->orders()->create($order)`

`return $menu->id`